# Passing ajax response to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

AJAX/JS noob here. I have the following AJAX code that returns some data from a php service. I am trying to find out how to assign the data that returns from the php service to some JS variable which I later want to display on the UI.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data1;  
   $(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("get_location.php", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#data').html(data);
            data1 = data; 
            });
        }, 500); 
   });
alert(data1);
</script>
```

And I have a variable in another script instance:

```
<script>
    var some_var1;
    var some_var2;
</script>
```

I have two questions that I have been stuck on for a while:

1. The way my PHP returns the data is though echo, meaning I do this in PHP:

   echo $var1;
     echo $var2;

Is this the right way to pass the data to AJAX given that I need it more structured?

2. Assuming I did #1 correctly, how do I assign "data" from AJAX to some_var1/some_var2 in JS?

Comment: 1. You probably want to look into [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). 2. There is only one way to assign a value to variable: `variable = value;`. The more challenging part with async code is when it's safe to *read* the variable.

Comment: What is the 'value' here? 'data'? And where do I place this code? I have two separate 'script'.

Comment: `value` is whatever you want to assign. In your case it would be `data`. All scripts are executed in the same global scope. But again, setting variables inside an Ajax callback is not that useful since you won't know *when* the variables will have the new value. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 instead.

Comment: I am trying to test reading 'data' and it's not working. For example alert(data); does not do anything...

Comment: You might not have placed `alert(data)` correctly in your code. Can't help you without a *complete* example.

Comment: Well, `data` is not defined where you are trying to access it. Here is a simplified example: `function foo(bar) { }; alert(bar);` Would you expect that to work? Did you have a look at the linked question at all? This might help you more: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196

Comment: How about this? Still does not work...:/

Comment: Again: Read the linked questions. There are all about that exact issue.

Comment: Looking into these links now...thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81091/discussion-between-moshikafya-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and you have already included JQuery in your html, you need to use javascript variables.

if your `console.log(data)` is actually logging something to the console, put `var ajaxData;`, or something before your JQuery function, and replace your `console.log(data)` it with `ajaxData = data;`.

Comment: See my edit above, it's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: is the issue that you can't call data in a different script?

Comment: Yes exactly, although it does update a div that I have every 0.5 seconds:        <div id="data"></div>